# Dynamically calling asynchronous script inside a div container

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, iframe

I am appending an external script to a div with Jquery/JS. I cannot include the external script in the head. I need to append it to a div which is being created with Jquery. The external script loads asynchronously, uses document.write and I have no control over that script.

What I want ultimately is to load the external script and append it to the div dynamically. I'm creating this div on the fly with JavaScript. So this has to be done only in js, not in html. If I place the external script in html statically it would work, but will not render content inside the div container. However when I place it dynamically it won't work.

Here's what I tried.  But I cannot see the script nor the object getting appended inside div. I need to put in the script inside div so that it renders content inside it.

```
// this is the external code
// the externalscript.js takes in the value of externalprop1 & renders an iframe inside "div2" so externalobject has to be defined before the externalscript.js is called.  
var externalobject = {
    externalprop1 = "prop1"
};

var newscript      = document.createElement("script")
    newscript.type = "text/javascript"
    newscript.src  = "externalscript.js"

// end of external code

dynamic_content =  '<li>';
dynamic_content += '<div class=" div1">';
dynamic_content += '<div class="div2" id= "div2here"></div>';
dynamic_content += '</div>';
dynamic_content += '</li>';
```

I have appended dynamic_content to the body & then I am doing:

```
$('#div2here').append(newscript);
```

Comment: If the external script uses `document.write()`, it is purposed to be loaded at parsing time, not after the page has been parsed. You simply can't use it, since it will open a new document and wipe out all the content of the old document.

Comment: Maybe grab the original script & find/replace all the `document.write` calls with other appropriate DOM manipulation

Comment: @Teemu So you mean I cannot append it dynamically to the div2?

Comment: I have no control over external script & I cannot manipulate it. is there any other way out?

Comment: May be, if you give more context on the situation (what is the script for example) you can be better helped.

Comment: it's something similar to google adsense. It renders ads

Comment: document.write only works correctly before the page is loaded. Can't say if it's your case with such an undocumented issue.

Answer (score 0):

If my guess is correct, you are putting script into div just because you need to load a script from remote location.

**Idea 1:**

Perhaps server hosting remote script allows CORS. In such case you could simply use something like jQuery getScript function to execute remote content:

```
$.getScript( 'externalscript.js' );
```

There are many ways to get and execute scripts from remote locations (i.e. [ScriptManJS](http://scriptman.js)) but as you are not able to load remote content, you should probably stick with what is currently available to you - JQuery or plain JavaScript.

**Idea 2:**

If remote host does not support CORS (browser throws exception in debugger console and nothing happens), perhaps you have some server of your own which you could use as a proxy? Your server could download required script and then allow your code to download it using AJAX (either cross-domain or locally, depending what system you are modifying). In this way you could bypass the CORS limitation.

**Idea 3:**

Finally, why do you say that you are not able to put script into head using JavaScript? Did you try something like (I think newscript should be used as a jQuery object in this case):

```
$('head').append( $( newscript ) );
```

Comment: Idea 3: "it would work & render content inside the div container", with `document.write()`. That's why not into head, though it won't work in a `div` either ...

Answer (score 0):

> If I place the external script in html statically it would work, but will not render content
>     inside the div container. However when I place it dynamically it won't work.

If you made it work adding it to the html, may be it is possible to add it to a hidden div, and when you need it, you can move it to the dynamically created div.

Comment: I did that but it won't work. I tried hiding it & then did .show() by appending it to the div but it does not append

Answer (score 0):

You could override the native `document.write` method before loading the external script. Something like this:

```
document.write = function (html) {
    document.getElementById('div2here').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
};
var newscript = document.createElement("script");
                     :
```

[`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.insertAdjacentHTML) does pretty much the same as `document.write`, except it doesn't wipe out the document.

Comment: what's the id that I should give in here document.getElementById('scripthere'). not clear.  There's no id for external scriptthat I see

Comment: You've `div2here`, my snippet seems to have an inherited `id` from my testing code. I've fixed the issue.

Comment: oh ok. & what 'beforeend' exactly doing ?

Comment: It tells the method to insert the `html` just before end of `#div2here`. For further information, please read the MDN article I've linked in the answer.